# how to set metadata(cmis:name and cmis:description) while creating the folder in share point from Pega

Tags: sharepoint, cmis, pega

[image]

We need to set description on folder while creating folder in Sharepoint from page.

Attached screenshot has only the details to create the folder and to set folder name.

How can we add a description for that folder at creation time?

Comment: Attached screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please utilize the OOTB "Title" property, or you can create your own custom property to set the description as the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting cmis:name and cmis:objectTypeId, which is great. If you want to set the description, have you tried setting the cmis:description property?

If you need help figuring out the properties that are available and their IDs, you might want to download and run the [Apache Chemistry CMIS Workbench](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html). You can point it at your CMIS service URL and browse the data dictionary, run queries, and inspect/modify objects.

Comment: i have tried cmis:description along with cmis:name, because i have to set the metadata while creating/saving the folder/document. Even though, exception was thrown " One or more of the input parameters to the service method is missing or invalid."

Comment: How can we set the metadata to existing folder/document? This answer might help me

Comment: There are several code samples at https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/